# How to get value based on some condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get death column or feature using value from `kill` and condition from `player` and `opponent`. The table will looks like this

| Player | Opponent | Kill |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dicey | OXY | 4 |
| OXY | dicey | 6 |
| Verno | dapr | 5 |
| dapr | Verno | 7 |

and how I transform it into

| Player | Opponent | Kill | Death |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dicey | OXY | 4 | 6 |
| OXY | dicey | 6 | 4 |
| Verno | dapr | 5 | 7 |
| dapr | Verno | 7 | 5 |

I'm expecting to get `death` by using `kill` column as for the value from condition each `player` and `opponent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will do it:

```
import pandas

data_frame = {'Player': ['dicey', 'OXY', 'Verno', 'dapr'],
    'Opponent': ['OXY', 'dicey', 'dapr', 'Verno'],
    'Kill': [4, 6, 5, 7]}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data_frame)
df['Death'] = df.apply(lambda row: df.loc[(df['Player'] == row['Opponent']) &
                                          (df['Opponent'] == row['Player']), 'Kill'].values[0], axis=1)
print(df)
```

Comment: @Octa, this is really not an ideal solution as it will have a quadratic complexity. I encourage you to give a try to the `merge` solutions, especially if you have a large dataset.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) combined with [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
out = df.merge(df.rename(columns={'Player': 'Opponent',
                                  'Opponent': 'Player',
                                  'Kill': 'Death'}),
               how='left') # or how='outer' depending of the desired output
```

Output:

```
  Player Opponent  Kill  Death
0  dicey      OXY     4      6
1    OXY    dicey     6      4
2  Verno     dapr     5      7
3   dapr    Verno     7      5
```

Comment: You likely want `how='outer'` for unmatched pairs

Comment: @rafaelc yes good point, or maybe `how='left'`?

Comment: I think `how=left` removes some value. For example, if the original df is `df = df.append(pd.Series(['aspas','dapr',5], index=df.iloc[0].index), ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @rafaelc I see your (valid) point, however this also add an extra row. Not sure what OP really would need in this case. Anyway, given the fact that an answer with `apply` was selected, I doubt this is really a concern to them ;)

Comment: Makes sense ;p your approach would be the one I would do too

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to merge the dataframe with itself.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Player': 'dicey', 'Opponent': 'OXY', 'Kill': 4},
    {'Player': 'OXY', 'Opponent': 'dicey', 'Kill': 6},
    {'Player': 'Verno', 'Opponent': 'dapr', 'Kill': 5},
    {'Player': 'dapr', 'Opponent': 'Verno', 'Kill': 7},
])

print(df.merge(df, left_on='Opponent', right_on='Player', suffixes=['', '_y']).rename(columns={'Kill_y': 'Death'}).drop(columns=['Player_y', 'Opponent_y']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create list of Opponent and access their kills using conditional operators.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Player'] = ['di', 'o', 'v', 'da']
df['Opponent'] = ['o', 'di', 'da', 'v']
df['Kill'] = [4, 6, 5, 7]
opponent_list = list(df['Oppenent'])
kill_list = []
for opponent in opponent_list:
    kill_list.append(df[df['Player'] == opponent]['Kill'].values[0])
df['Death'] = kill_list
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way using `df.join()`:

```
df.join(df.set_index(['Opponent','Player'])['Kill'].rename('Death'),on = ['Player','Opponent'])
```

or you could also use `frozenset` and reverse the list for each `group`:

```
df['Death'] = df['Kill'].groupby(df[['Player','Opponent']].apply(frozenset,axis=1)).transform(lambda x: x.tolist()[::-1])
```

Output:

```
  Player Opponent  Kill  Death
0  dicey      OXY     4      6
1    OXY    dicey     6      4
2  Verno     dapr     5      7
3   dapr    Verno     7      5
```